# Parallel version of sub selecting and assignment on R data frames

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have two data frames DF1 & DF2 and I do some lookup and assignments
The code below works but take ages to complete and therefore I am looking for a parallel version of the code to speed up a bit the process
Thank you in advance

```
dim(DF1)
[1] 5000000 50
dim(DF2)
[1] 30000000 5

for (i in 1:5000000){
   # sub-select DF2 based on the value of DF1$symbol
   temp = filter(DF2, symbol == DF1$symbol[i])
   # find the position of DF2 based on the value of DF1$date
   position=which(temp$date == DF1$date[i])
   #sub-select temp based on the value of the position
   temp=temp[(position-10):(position+10) ,]
   #
   DF1$V1[i] = (temp$VV1[10] - temp$VV1[1])
   DF1$V2[i] = (temp$VV1[21] - temp$VV1[1])
   DF1$V3[i] = (temp$VV2[10])
   DF1$V4[i] = (temp$VV3[10])
}
```

Comment: Is your `symbol` elements all unique?  If there are duplicates, I would assume a join by group maybe faster

Comment: Post output of `summary(DF1)` and `summary(DF2)`

Comment: akrun, yes there are duplicated symbols

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is not clear whether this works or not.  Try `library(data.table);setDT(DF1)[DF1[DF2, {position <- which(date == i.date); minus_10 <- position-10; plus_10 <- position + 10; V1 <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) {i1 <- x:y; VV[10] - VV[1]}, minus_10, plus_10));  .(V1 = V1)}, on = .(symbol), by = .EACHI], V1 := V1, on = .(symbol)]`

Comment: Thank you akrun. I will try to post a small a reproducible example but the main question is how to make the code to run in parallel. Of course a more efficient code is more than welcome but I try to utilize 16 cores.

Comment: Regarding "Of course a more efficient code is more than welcome but I try to utilize 16 cores": Note that **data.table** already performs lots of its operations in parallel using multi-_threaded_ processing.  Because of this, there is often little gain, or even a negative gain, in parallelizing on top of this.